# More concise way to construct a query string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I don't write a lot of JavaScript. The following code works, but is there a more concise way of writing this? I want to construct a query string which will be appended to a URL from variables that could possibly be null. If all the values are null, I want an empty string. jQuery is available for me to use (and I am using it).

```
constructQueryString = function(code, flag) {
    var qsObj = {};

    if ( code ) {
        qsObj["code"] = code;
    }
    if ( flag ) {
        qsObj["flag"] = flag;
    }
    return ( !$.isEmptyObject(qsObj) ) ? "?" + $.param(qsObj) : "";
}
```

Some tests:

```
console.log(constructQueryString("XXXXXX", "true"));
// ?code=XXXXXX&flag=true
console.log(constructQueryString(null, "true"));
// ?flag=true
console.log(constructQueryString("XXXXXX", null));
// ?code=XXXXXX
console.log(constructQueryString(null, null));
// (an empty string)
```

**UPDATE**: Below is some more context showing how I am using the code in our project.

```
code = $el.attr("data-code") || null;
flag = $el.attr("data-flag") || null;
qsObj = {};

if ( code ) {
    qsObj["code"] = code;
}
if ( flag ) {
    qsObj["flag"] = flag;
}
queryString = ( !$.isEmptyObject(qsObj) ) ? "?" + $.param(qsObj) : "";

$.ajax({
    "type": "POST", "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "url": url + queryString,
    "data": JSON.stringify(reqBody)
});
```

Comment: Why don't you pass an object?

Comment: Agree with zeroflagL : what do you want to do with this string ? Maybe  using an object is the better choice.

Comment: An object or array would serve you better.

Comment: zeroflagL, M'sieur Toph', DevlshOne: I updated the question with some more context. I don't actually have a function, constructQueryString-- I just created that to simplify things.

Comment: Should this question be moved to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?